# How to create a widget instance in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-widgets, jquery-ui-widget-factory

Consider I have two widgets.

```
$.widget( "custom.car", {
    options: {
        name: ''
    },
    _create: function() {
        this.options.name = 'car'
    },
    random: function( event ) {
        console.log(this.options.name);
    },
    clear: function() { console.log('Clear'); }
});

$.widget( "custom.bike", {
    options: {
        name: ''
    },
    _create: function() {
        this.options.name = 'bike'
    },
    random: function( event ) {
        console.log(this.options.name);
    },
    clear: function() { console.log('Clear'); }
});
```

`isCar` and `isBike` is based on user input.

```
if(isCar) {
   $( "div" ).car();
   $( "div" ).car('random');
} else if(isBike) {
   $( "div" ).bike();
   $( "div" ).bike('random');
}
```

If I call the `random` method in some where place I'll write the `if` condition.
If any possible solution to avoid the `if` condition or any other solution.

Note: My question is correct or not?

Comment: You're trying to avoid the if else statement?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, you'll have to decide which method you want to call so you'll have to use an `if...else if` construct or at least a ternary operator.

Here is an example that reduces the number of statements:

```
var fName = isCar ? "car" : "bike";
$( "div" )[fName]();
$( "div" )[fName]('random');
```

In this example I assume that if `isCar` is `false` `isBike` is `true` which is not exactly like your example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information missing from your post but here is a way to avoid an "if else" statement.

```
<form id="selection">
  <input id="car-radio" type="radio" value="car" checked> Car
  <input id="bike-radio" type="radio" value="bike"> Bike
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var carFunc = function() {
        isCar = true;
        isBike = false;

        $( "div" ).car();
        $( "div" ).car('random');
    }

    var bikeFunc = function() {
       isCar = false;
       isBike = true;

       $( "div" ).bike();
       $( "div" ).bike('random');
    }

    $("#selection").on('click', '#car-radio', carFunc);
    $("#selection").on('click', '#bike-radio', bikeFunc);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes i'm trying to avoid if condition. But you are mentioned two different element. I have one element based on the input i switch the widget.

Comment: How do you get the user input? @Viji